# Runtime ImportError in Python executable created using PyInstaller

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller, python-asyncio

I'm trying to get my feet wet with Python's asyncio module and have a simple script that runs fine but when I compile it using PyInstaller and run the executable it creates I get a runtime ImportError that I can't figure out how to fix.
I've spent several hours scouring the internet to see if anyone else has encountered the same issue but haven't been able to find anything and I don't understand what's causing the issue.

The script I'm compiling looks like this:

```
import requests
import asyncio


async def main():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    futures = [
        loop.run_in_executor(
            None,
            requests.get,
            'http://google.com'
        )
        for i in range(5)
    ]
    for response in await asyncio.gather(*futures):
        print(response.status_code)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

The command I use to compile the script is:

```
pyinstaller -F async_test.py
```

And the runtime exception that is thrown when running the executable that PyInstaller creates is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asyncio\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name '_overlapped'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Miscellaneous\async_test.py", line 2, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "asyncio\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
[13048] Failed to execute script async_test
```

I'm using Python 3.6.4 and PyInstaller 3.4

If someone could shed some light on what the problem is and how to fix it I'd be very grateful.

Comment: It works properly with the combination of Python 3.7.3, PyInstaller 3.4, requests 2.21.0. Would you like to upgrade python?